# Creating WooCommerce follow-up email custom field that prints out some of the product details selected in a drop down box

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce/WordPress site that has several product courses. I am trying to create a follow-up email using the follow-up email plugin that includes the date range selected for the course (the date range is selected in the form as a drop down text list, one possible data selection would be something like '7 Feb 2017 to 14 Feb 2017')

The data is not available in the follow up email plugin as a standard field such as {customer_name}. I have tried to use the custom field generator for a specific product unsuccessfully, fields such as _product_attributes return 'Array' and I have no idea how to access the array elements through the WordPress console without editing the source code, which I am hoping to avoid.

Can someone let me know 1. if the custom fields is where I should be looking and 2. If so how do I access the array elements.

Thanks